# Get position of each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, offset

```js
$(function(){

    var $animatedEls = $(".marked");

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {

            var offset = 0;

            $.each($animatedEls, function(i, item) {

                offset = $(item).offset().top;

                console.log($(item).offset());

            });

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
<div>...</div>
<h2 class="marked">This sucks.</h2>
```

I am trying to get the position of some matched elements when scrolling.
The output is however the same number for each element.

Output:

```
Object {top: 2480, left: 0}
Object {top: 2480, left: 0}
Object {top: 2480, left: 0}
```

Why is the offset the same for each element?
The values are also changing when I scroll.

EDIT: Okay. The snippet works on here, but not on my site. Highly annoying.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please..

Comment: what do you think is `$(".animated").each..`? it should be `$animatedEl.each..` or `$('.marked').each..`

Comment: You are not using the .each function right. you should use .each(index, item)

Comment: Try to bind it to a .click event, see if its working on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the use of .each.

It should be used like this:

```
var $animatedEls = $('.marked');

        $(window).scroll(function(e) {

            $.each($animatedEls, function(index, item) {
                console.log($(item).offset());
            }

        }
```

Comment: No, that has no effect.

Comment: did you changed the "this" to "item? post fiddle plz if yes, because it should work.\

Comment: You are right, it should work. There must be something on my site that messes with the results.