# how to log scroll events to console with javascript

Tags: javascript, events, scroll

I want to output to the `console` the x and y changes of any scroll event on the window - just to test something.
How do you do this with plain JS?

Comment: Check out this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291125/get-position-of-each-element/30291593#30291593

Comment: oh yeah - also I don't want to use Jquery, just plain js...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
window.onscroll=function(){
   console.log( 
     'top: '  + (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop) + ' ' +
     'left: ' + (window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft)
   );
}
```

```html
asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>
```

Edit:

Instead of setting the function directly, you can also use:     `window.addEventListener('click', func, false)`.

Note that for backward compatibility (notably < IE9) you'd need `attachEvent`, here is a basic [workaround](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/addeventlistenerattachevent.htm):

```
function addEventHandler(elem, eventType, handler) {
 if (elem.addEventListener)
     elem.addEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
 else if (elem.attachEvent)
     elem.attachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler); 
}
```

Comment: cool, seems to work! one question though - why is `window.pageYOffset` not enough - why the `document.documentElement.scrollTop` thing?

Comment: Because there exists some thing called IE, and we still need some backwards compatibility, just as with the `addEventListener` versus `addEventListener` thing.

Comment: right. well, I figured it was a browser compatibility issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the scroll you can do:

```
var scrollX = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft; 
var scrollY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

and to capture the scrolling event on pure Javascript:

```
function myScript(){
    var scrollX = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    var scrollY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    console.log('Scroll X:'+scrollX+' Scroll Y:'+scrollY)
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScript);
```

You can call `myScript()` manually and it will return valid values too

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', console.log);
```